# Как создать класс контейнер который будет обладать динамическим списком объектов, являющихся экземплярами производных классов?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Я уже поработал над ним, главное задание - это создать иерархию классов, конструкторы перемещения и копирования с которыми я вроде справился.

На данный момент нужно реализовать класс контейнер который будет обладать динамическим списком объектов, являющихся экземплярами производных классов по иерархии наследования. Как это можно сделать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Car
{
public:
    string* m_name;

public:
    Car() {}  // Конструктор по умолчанию 

    ~Car()
    {
        delete m_name;
    }

    Car(const Car& x) // Конструктор копирования
    {
        this->m_name = new string;
        this->m_name = x.m_name;

    }

    Car& operator=(const Car& x)
    {
        if (&x == this)
            return *this;

        delete m_name;

        this->m_name = new string;
        this->m_name = x.m_name;

        return *this;
    }

    Car(Car&& x) : m_name(x.m_name)
    {
        x.m_name = nullptr;
    }

    Car& operator=(const Car&& x)
    {
        if (&x == this)
            return *this;

        delete m_name;

        this->m_name = x.m_name;
        *x.m_name = nullptr;

        return *this;
    }

    string getName()
    {
        return string();
    }

    virtual void info()
    {
        cout << "Vehicle : " << endl;
    }

};

class BMW : public Car
{
public:
    BMW() {}  // Конструктор по умолчанию 

    BMW(const Car& x) // Конструктор копирования
    {
        this->m_name = new string;
        this->m_name = x.m_name;
    }

    BMW& operator=(const Car& x)
    {
        if (&x == this)
            return *this;

        delete m_name;

        this->m_name = new string;
        this->m_name = x.m_name;

        return *this;
    }

    BMW(Car&& x)
    {
        x.m_name = nullptr;
    }

    BMW& operator=(const Car&& x)
    {
        if (&x == this)
            return *this;

        delete m_name;

        this->m_name = x.m_name;
        *x.m_name = nullptr;

        return *this;
    }


    void info() override
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "BMW M3 " << endl;
        cout << "250 kmph " << endl;
        cout << "333 hp " << endl;
        cout << "4 speed automatic " << endl;
        cout << "rear weel drive " << endl;
    }
};

class CarContainer
{
private: vector<Car*>_container;
       Car o;
public: CarContainer() = default;
      CarContainer(CarContainer&) = delete;
      CarContainer(CarContainer&& another) : _container(move(another._container)) {}
      ~CarContainer();
};


int main()
{

    Car* unicycle;

    unicycle = new Car;
    unicycle->info();
    delete unicycle;

    unicycle = new BMW;
    unicycle->info();
    delete unicycle;

}
```

Comment: Вы уверены что ниже приведёт **минимальный** воспроизводимый пример?...

Comment: Да, была ошибка, я ее исправил. А что значит "минимальный воспроизводимый пример" ?

Comment: Можно подробней ознакомиться [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), это минимальный пример, без лишних деталей, который может воспроизвести ошибку которая у вас выходит (например). А так вообще разнится от случая к случаю, лучше стоит ознакомиться в справке.

Comment: Спасибо, я понял что это. Сделал самый минимальный пример для того что бы понять задачу!

Comment: Отлично, ваш код в вопросе уже стал более читаемым, теперь надо сконцентрировать вопрос на **одной** конкретной задаче, если нужно сделать две задачи, разделите это на два вопроса, также предоставьте ваши попытки решения (какие бы они не были, правильные или неправильные, с ошибками или без). Это увеличит шансы на то что на ваш вопрос ответят, плюс к тому вы получите репутацию за хороший вопрос, которая в будущем даст вам доп. возможности на сайте.

Comment: Готово, мне бы тогда хотя бы с первым пунктом получить помощь

Comment: Хорошо, теперь я отправил свою правку для улучшения вашего вопроса, код снизу это как я понимаю то, о чём вы написали в самом начале? Единственной вещи который не хватает у вас в вопросе это попыток решения задачи самому, это бы сделало ваш вопрос очень хорошим примером для остальных участников задающих вопросы. Постарайтесь отправить любую вашу реализацию которую вы смогли сделать, даже если она не делает того что вы хотите. Главное показать то что вы пытались решить задачу самостоятельно.

Comment: Я пытался решить эту задачу самостоятельно, я крайне редко прибегаю к использованию подобных форумов, это конечный результат

Comment: То что вы пытались решить задачу самостоятельно, замечательно, но эту попытку решения нужно добавить в вопрос, я ничего лично против вас не имею, это правила сайта, о них написано [в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Я всего лишь пытаюсь привести ваш вопрос к стандартам сайта.

Comment: Ладно, тогда попрошу помощь в другом месте